# Why does an empty transaction persist my entity (doctrine)?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine entity which is being persisted to the database without me ever calling persist or flush.

I've managed to reproduce the problem quite simply below. As you will see, this script loads a row from a database table called MyEntity and obtains a php object with the row's fields as attributes. The script then changes one of the attributes, but does not call persist or flush. Then the script create an empty transaction which does nothing. Oddly, this makes the object persist in the sense that the changes made to the php object are also made in the database. I wouldn't have expected this script to make any changes to the database.

What is happening here?

Note that if I remove the empty transaction, the problem dissapears and no change is made to the database.

Here is the code (**test.php**):

```
<?php

    use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

    require_once("Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php");
    Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR();

    $classloader = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('testEntities', __DIR__);
    $classloader->register();

    $paths = array();
    $isDevMode = true;
    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
    $dbParams = array("driver" => "pdo_mysql",
        "host" => "localhost",
        "user" => "username",
        "password" => "password",
        "dbname" => "databaseName",
        "charset" => "utf8");

    $em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
    $em->getConnection()->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");

    $matches = $em->getRepository('testEntities\\MyEntity')->findBy(array('ID' => 1));
    echo("<pre>");

    if (!empty($matches)) {
        $object = $matches[0];
        print_r($object);
        $object->Content = "WILL IT BLEND?";
        print_r($object);
    }
    $em->transactional(function($em) {
        // Nothing happens here, but if I comment out the call to transactional, the behaviour of the script changes.
    });

    echo("</pre>Done!");
?>
```

Create and fill MyEntity table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `MyEntity` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Content` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;

INSERT INTO MyEntity (ID, Content) VALUES (NULL, "Hello World");
```

Create MyEntity doctrine Entity (**testEntities\MyEntity.php**):

```
<?php

    namespace testEntities;

    /** @Entity @Table(name="MyEntity")*/
    class MyEntity
    {
        /**
         * @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") @Column(type="integer") 
         */
        public $ID;

        /**
         * @Column(type="string", length=500)
         */
        public $Content;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine manual: 9. Transactions and Concurrency -> [9.1.2. Approach 2: Explicitly](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-2-explicitly) (at section bottom):

> The difference between Connection#transactional($func) and
>   EntityManager#transactional($func) is that the latter abstraction
>   flushes the EntityManager prior to transaction commit and also closes
>   the EntityManager properly when an exception occurs (in addition to
>   rolling back the transaction).

So: `EntityManager#transactional($func)` flushes the EntityManager prior to transaction commit (if `$func` call was successful - your case).

Comment: It may fluch the EntityManager, but if I have never called persist, it shouldn't save anything to the database, should it?

Comment: No, you are wrong. It depends on tracking policy. Read about [Tracking Policies](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#change-tracking-policies) in manual. Default policy is Deferred Implicit. _With this policy, Doctrine detects the changes by a property-by-property comparison at commit time and also detects changes to entities or new entities that are referenced by other managed entities (“persistence by reachability”)_.

Comment: If you add `@ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")` annotation to `class MyEntity`, your higher comment becomes true and Doctrine must stop save changes of your example.

Comment: I see. It works now in this example. In my actual code it doesn't, so the problem must be somewhere else. I will start a new question once I've managed to reproduce the problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I changed EntityManager#beginTransaction to Connection#beginTransaction, but it didnt help - entites are still persisted even though I didnt called persist on them.